# alternatives to setAttribute

Tags: javascript

I've been creating elements in a different way and I'm not sure the best approach.  What is the difference between:

```
var myselect = document.createElement("select");
myselect.name="blah";
```

and

```
var myselect = document.createElement("select");
myselect.setAttribute("name", "blah");
```

I just recently got tripped up by using:

```
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.for= "blah";
```

Which doesn't work and I had to use setAttribute.  Are there advantages/disadvantages of one versus another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you want to deal with *properties* in JavaScript instead of *attributes*.

Properties are on DOM nodes. Attributes are in HTML markup. Sometimes attributes automatically translate to properties.

With respect to `for`, use `htmlFor` instead.

```
var label = document.createElement("label");
label.htmlFor= "CameraQuality";
```

Comment: thx!  What about the case where I did this: `myform.setAttribute("onclick", "return validate()");`

Comment: @TomPepernic: You could use an attribute in that case, but it will ultimately create a function on the property, so you could just do this: `myform.onclick = function() { return validate(); };`. There will be some slight differences between the functions, but nothing that you'll likely need to be concerned with.

Comment: hrmm, that didn't work for some reason.  No errors, I get nothing from my validate routine...